# How to get the number of characters of monospaced font in a line of wrapped text in NSTextView?

Tags: swift, string, font-size, nstextview

I would like to know how many letters has one full line of the wrapped text which consists of letters without white spaces and line brake in NSTextView. Font of the text is defined as monospaced font. I cannot find how to get the width for the font (I have thought that I can calculate it from the width of the NSTextView and the width of the font).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text view contains *one full line or more*:

```
var range = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)
textView.layoutManager?.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(0, effectiveRange: &range)

print(range.length) // number of characters that can be fitted on a single line
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer!